# Raster Image Importation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, image

I am trying to open a raster image file in Arcmap 10.3 . I have the AUX File, a JGW file , 2 XML Document files ,and a RRD file. It imports into Arcmap 9. However, Arcmap 10.3 does not import the image. Can someone help me?

Comment: Separate the JGW and JPG files into a new folder (copy) then try. It could be one of the AUX files is bad, these files contain metadata and statistics - not so important if you just want to *use* the image but vital for extra information like accuracy and currency etc.. The RRD isn't supported as Wes said but should be just ignored. Does the image open OK in your default JPG viewer, it's not corrupt is it? Does the information in the world file (JGW) look right (6 numbers on 6 lines)? It should open in Notepad (or similar text editor).

Answer (score 3):

RRD (reduced resolution dataset) files are no longer supported by ArcMap, since version 10.1 I believe. By the looks of that, you have an RRD, which is a pyramid set based on an original raster, but no the original data. ArcMap now uses a different type of pyramid with a `.tif.ovr` file extension. You should be looking for an associated jpeg, the original data. ArcMap will not open pyramid files alone, and the original raster will be needed.

The JGW file is a jpeg "world file" that gives it a spatial reference, and the AUX file associates the RRD with the original file, and the two XMLs are likely metadata and processing information.

EDIT: One option you might have--and I'm not 100% positive this will work because I do not have access to ArcMap 9--is to import the file into 9 and export it as a raster dataset of some kind (like a jpeg or tiff) and then import that new file into ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Sry @Wes. the original .JPG file is included as well. But i should try changing the format from Arc 9.